# Creating multiple directories in 3 directories Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have created 3 folders named Paul, James & Kurt.

In each folder that I've created I must also have 3 folders named (Documents, Pictures, Music).

And also

Each named folder should have a README file containing the following contents:
        "These folders are used to store employee details."

Can some kindly guide me through this

Comment: Do you need help in creating files in all those directories? I didn't follow up your question, would you provide more info?

Comment: You know how to create folder (or directories), so creating `Documents` etc. should be doable. `echo "These folders are used to store employee details." > README` will create your file.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

for names in $(cat "users.txt");

do

mkdir "$names"

done                                      .............I used this bash script and I want to add the creation of a text file in the folders to it

Answer (score 1):

The below will create new directories for all lines in `users.txt` and a sub-directory in each for `Documents` with a `README` in it with the above contents. Hope it helps.

```
Sub=Documents
for names in $(cat "users.txt"); do
    mkdir -p "$names"/{"$Sub",} && touch "$names"/"$Sub"/README.txt && 
echo "These folders are used to store employee details." > "$names"/"$Sub"/README.txt
done
```